# Помогите построить реляционный запрос

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Есть 3 таблицы:

Первая с записями "post":

```
id | name | content
```

Вторая с категориями "category":

```
id | name
```

Третья связи "route"

```
id_post | id_category
```

ид'ы категорий я получаю из чекбокса

```
while ($cat = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) echo '<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="'.$cat['id'].'"/> '.$cat['name'];
```

как видно, категорий может быть несколько для каждой записи. Вообщем я не помогу сообразить как построить запрос. MySQL::PDO

```
 $db->prepare("", array());
```

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, на каждую категорию должна быть одна запись в связующей таблице, поэтому либо делается столько запросов, сколько чекбоксов, либо один, используя синтаксис

    INSERT INTO route (id_post, id_category) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)...

Второй случай хуже тем, что там не получится по-человечески использовать плейсхолдеры в PDO (хотя никто не запретит динамически генерировать запрос с плейсхолдерами `:category1`, `:category2` и т.п.).

Comment: @Fike, я даже представить это всё не смогу (: первый случай с кол-вом запросов отпадает наверное, потому что категории могут как добавляться, так и удалятся, и каждый раз не получится добавлять или удалять запросы.

Comment: А как по другому сделать эту "мультикатегорийность" я тоже не знаю, тем более нужно присутствие сортировки по категориям что-бы можно было вывести записи которые находятся в какой-то определенной категории.

Comment: > потому что категории могут как добавляться, так и удалятся, и каждый раз не получится добавлять или удалять запросы.

Почему это?

* Оценить статус записи (новый пост/существующий пост)
* Загрузить текущие категории (новый пост -> пустой массив)
* Загрузить проставленные пользователем категории
* Существующие категории, отсутствующие в проставленных, удалить (здесь поможет функция `array_diff()`)
* Проставленные категории, отсутствующие в существующих, добавить (тот же `array_diff()`)

Comment: вообщем ничего не получилось, уже вторые сутки не помогу понять как реализовать мультикатегории.